# operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type string and bool

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, wcf

I have an issue where I run the code snippet below and it gives me the error:

> operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'bool'

```
    var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
    {
        SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Ali Bottom Rail" && x.Section == TruckSection.FrontEndRequirments).First(),
        StockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Corrugated" ? db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "AEX165").First() : null,
    };
    qisg.Quantity = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : 1;
    //Error in the line below
    qisg.Length = qisg.StockItem == null ? 0 : (double)quoteItem.ExternalWidth + quoteItem.BodyType.Name = "Royal Corrugated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Glued" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Smooth Folded" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Riveted" ? -0.136 : -0.020;
    quoteItem.SectionGroups.Add(qisg);
```

How would I be able to do the same type of thing with coding different than using the `'||'` operator?

Comment: place braces `(...)` around condition

Comment: Something something operator precedence. Did you try searching?

Comment: It seems that you mean `quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Corrugated"` not just `"Royal Corrugated"`

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Yes thank you for pointing out my simple stupid mistake! :D

Comment: And thanks for who ever downvoted :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
(double)quoteItem.ExternalWidth + quoteItem.BodyType.Name = "Royal Corrugated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Glued" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Smooth Folded" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Riveted" ? -0.136 : -0.020;
```

to

```
(double)quoteItem.ExternalWidth + ( quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Corrugated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Glued" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Smooth Folded" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Riveted" ? -0.136 : -0.020 );
```

The changes:

- Paranthesis around the ternary so that it is more readable.
- quoteItem.BodyType.Name = "Royal Corrugated", this is wrong it should be two = which is ==

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) But as @DmitryBychenko pointed out first I will give him the correct answer if he posts as answer, if he doesn't I will give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

That comes from this snippet:

```
"Royal Corrugated" || quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Glued"
```

The == operator has precedence over the || operator.

So `quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Royal Smooth Glued"` is converted to a boolean. Then you essentially have `<string> || <bool>` which C# will not allow.